# What would be the most concise way to write below snippet in Java?

Tags: java, kotlin

```
val dbPort = props["mysqlPort"]?.get(0)?.toInt() ?: 3306
```

props is Map<String, List>

currently am writing it this way:

```
var portStr = props.get("mysqlPort").get(0);
var dbPort = (portStr == null) ? 3306 : Integer.parseInt(portStr);
```

is this correct? can it be better?

Comment: Your Java code isn't a 1:1 equivalent, because it throws NPE if `props.get("mysqlPort") == null`. Kotlin code handled that case properly. Other than that, I don't think you can make it much shorter in Java. You can use `Optional` and call `map()` multiple times, similar to Kotlin's `?.`, but I'm not sure if that would be a cleaner approach.

Comment: Of course, both Kotlin and Java versions would fail if the list is there, but is empty. Or if the value is not a string with an integer number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this.

```
static int mySqlPort(Map<String, List<String>> prop) {
    return Optional.ofNullable(prop.get("mysqlPort"))
        .map(x -> x.get(0))
        .map(Integer::parseInt)
        .orElse(3306);
}
```

test case:

```
System.out.println("normal:         " + mySqlPort(Map.of("mysqlPort", Arrays.asList("1234", "4567"))));
System.out.println("null port:      " + mySqlPort(Map.of("mysqlPort", Arrays.asList(null, "4567"))));
System.out.println("no 'mysqlPort': " + mySqlPort(Map.of("sqlitePort", Arrays.asList("1234", "4567"))));
```

result:

```
normal:         1234
null port:      3306
no 'mysqlPort': 3306
```